# Passing child of generic class fails in strategy pattern

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to implement a strategy pattern using generics in Typescript. The idea is to have one mapper with the key of all possible types, then the value would have all questions (to be rendered with React) needed for that particular type (it will be later extended to also have validations and other stuff tied to that type).

These are the objects to apply the pattern to

```js
export interface Book {
    id: string;
    type: string;
    title: string;
    author: string;
}

export interface Novel extends Book {
    genre: string;
}
```

This is the typing for the questions

```js
export interface BookQuestionProps<T> {
    book: T;
}

//implementation
export const titleQuestion: React.FunctionComponent<BookQuestionProps<Book>> = ({
    book
}: BookQuestionProps<Book>) => {
    return <input type="text" value={book.title} />
}

export const genreQuestion: React.FunctionComponent<BookQuestionProps<Novel>> = ({
    book
}: BookQuestionProps<Novel>) => {
    return <input type="text" value={book.genre} />
}
```

This is the main part of the pattern

```js
export interface BookMapperStrategy<T> {
    questions: React.FunctionComponent<BookQuestionProps<Book>>[]
}

export interface BookTypeMapperStrategy<T> {
    [type: string]: BookMapperStrategy<T>;
}
```

After all that setup, the implementation would look something like this

```js
//specific strategy for novel
const novelQuestions: React.FunctionComponent<BookQuestionProps<Novel>>[] = [
    titleQuestion,
    genreQuestion
]

const novelMapperStrategy: BookMapperStrategy<Novel> = {
    questions: novelQuestions
}

// setup strategy pattern mapper
const bookTypeMapperStrategy: BookTypeMapperStrategy<Book> = {
    novel: novelMapperStrategy,
}

//print questions
const novel: Novel = {
    id: '',
    type: 'novel',
    title: '',
    author: '',
    genre: ''
}

bookTypeMapperStrategy[novel.type].questions.map((question) => {
    React.createElement(question, {
        novel
    })
})
```

Typescript then gives me a compilation error on `novelQuestions`, specifically when setting `titleQuestion` in the array of the following:

```
Type 'FunctionComponent<BookQuestionProps<Book>>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<BookQuestionProps<Novel>>'.
  The types of 'propTypes.book' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Validator<Book>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<Novel>'.
      Type 'Book' is not assignable to type 'Novel'.ts(2322)
```

I have tried changing the interface into type union, but it gives even more error.

I would have thought that since `Novel` is a child of `Book`, passing in `titleQuestion` of type `React.FunctionComponent<BookQuestionProps<Book>>` to be part of `React.FunctionComponent<BookQuestionProps<Novel>>` would work, cause, `Book` is parent of `Novel`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's dumb but shouldn't `bookTypeMapperStrategy` be typeof `BookMapperStrategy<Novel>` since you try to add something of type `BookMapperStrategy<Novel>` in it ?

Comment: Hi Quentin! The main idea of the `bookTypeMapperStrategy` is so that it can take in any other types as well. For example, in the future, we would be adding `EBook` that extends from `Book` with a different key. So `bookTypeMapperStrategy` should still stay as `Book`, which would be the parent of both types